# Cordova Enable IOS Capabilities via CLI

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, in-app-purchase

I'm using a cordova plugin for in-app-purchases, but we build everything in the cloud thus I need a way to enable the in-app-purchases for xcode as part of my CI which basically means I need some cli commands to enable that. What are the possibilities here?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [XCODE CLI](https://mac.install.guide/commandlinetools/index.html), I do not know if there are switches to turn on in-app purchase though. Hopefully it does it....